# Why does a function expecting a reference work with a pointer?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm writing a program in C++ that uses a C library. This library takes pointers to functions for callbacks, and I want it to call instance methods. Fortunately, the library takes an extra data parameter that's just a "void *" and is passed unchanged to the callback. So, I created a generic callback wrapper function.

```
void callbackWrapper(std::function<void ()> &func) {
    func();
}
```

Now, when I need to register a callback in the library, I pass a pointer to the callbackWrapper function as the function to call, and a pointer to a std::function as the extra data parameter. When the callback happens, it calls my wrapper, which then calls the actual method/lambda/whatever I really wanted to call.

But, there's a bug in the above code. I used "&" rather than "*", which means the function is expecting a *reference* to a std::function, not a pointer. The function *should* have been defined like so:

```
void callbackWrapper(std::function<void ()> *func) {
    (*func)();
}
```

I didn't notice the bug for quite a while -- because it worked perfectly. I only noticed because I was tracking down an unrelated bug, and just happened to see it. So, my question is, why? I have three possible answers:

1. The C++ standard allows for automatic promotion of pointers to references in this circumstance.
2. My compiler (gcc 9.3.1) noticed the mismatch and silently fixed it for me.
3. The address of the pointer just happened to land in the right place in the stack frame that the call could succeed.

Are any of my theories correct? If not, what happened?

Comment: Implementation-defined.  A reference can be implemented any way the compiler sees fit.  There is no standard way to implement them.  A different compiler, or maybe even different compiler options, the code may no longer work.

Comment: @HTNW No, it wasn't `const`, though it probably should have been.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So, you're saying it was explanation #3? That the address just happened to land in the right place?

Comment: Possibly, or your compiler actually does implement that reference as a pointer.  Note that the C++ standard has no say over how a reference should be implemented, only how they're supposed to behave.

Comment: I'd be curious where you are passing in the callback in the first place, since I would have expected an error saying that the expected function signature `void(*)(void*)` didn't match the passed signature `void(*)(std::function<void()>&)`.  But definitely reason 3: it just happened to work

Comment: @DaveS The library in question just accepts `void *` for the callback type, so there's no type checking at all.

Comment: Well, then bad on them. Even C has function pointer arguments. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html for such an argument

Comment: Isn't it because `std::function<>` objects can be constructed from plain function pointers as well? Does it work if you try with any other type? Does your compiler accept passing an `int*` as parameter to a function expecting an `int&`?

Comment: @LouisCloete I was able to find a callback in the library that included a `double*` argument, and I set up a function that expected a `double&` argument in the same place, and yes, it worked just fine. I was even able to assign a value to it and later retrieve that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that case 3 is true for your example.

It is very sensible to pass references as if they were pointers, most ABIs likely do this.

For example, the Itanium C++ ABI [says](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#reference-parameter) (this is the ABI which is used for example on Linux/x64):

> Reference parameters are handled by passing a pointer to the object bound to the reference.